# How to retrieve only the relation ID, not the whole entity in MikroORM?

Tags: mikro-orm

I have the following basic test entities:

```
@Entity()
class Author {
    @PrimaryKey()
    public id!: number;

    @Property()
    public name!: string;
}

@Entity()
class Book {
    @PrimaryKey()
    public id!: number;

    @Property()
    public title!: string;

    @ManyToOne({joinColumn: 'authorID'})
    public author!: Author;
}
```

What i'm trying, is to select only a single Book record, with its 'author', but I care only about its **ID**, I **don't want to actually load the entity**.

If I simply call this, it won't work (no author data loaded at all):

```
em.getRepository(Book).findOne({id: 1}, {fields: ['id', 'title', 'author.id']});
```

'author.id' doesn't do the trick, the SQL doesn't even contain the 'authorID' field.

If I add 'author' to the fields list as well, it works, author is loaded (only with the ID), but as a separate entity, with a **separate, additional SQL statement**! That's what I'm trying to avoid.

```
em.getRepository(Book).findOne({id: 1}, {fields: ['id', 'title', 'author', 'author.id']})

@1. SQL
select `b0`.`id`, `b0`.`title`, `b0`.`authorID` from `book` as `b0` where `b0`.`id` = 1 limit 1

@2. SQL (this wouldn't be neccessary as I want only the ID)
select `a0`.`id` from `author` as `a0` where `a0`.`id` in (2)

--> Result:
Book: { id: 1, title: 'a book', author: { id: 2 } }
```

The only way I found is to add the specific 'authorID' field too to the Book entity:

```
@Property()
public authorID!: number;
```

But, I'd like to avoid introducing these foreign key columns, it would be better to handle through the already existing and used 'author' relation (only by the 'id' property).

Does any solution exists where I could retrieve a relation's ID without generating a 2nd SELECT statement (for the relation), and even avoid  introducing the foreign key (next to the already existing relation property)? Would be great to receive through the relation without any extra sql statement.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct behaviour you see the second query, that is how population works, and the fact that you want just a single property from the entity does not change anything, you still populate the relation, and each relation will use its own query to load it. You can use `LoadStrategy.JOINED` if you want to use a single query. But that would still do a join for that relation, which is not needed for your use case.

Given you only want the FK to be present, you dont need to care about the target entity at all. This should do the trick too:

```
em.getRepository(Book).findOne(1, {
  fields: ['id', 'title', 'author'],
  populate: [],
});
```

This way you say you want those 3 properties to be part of what's selected from the `Book` entity. You already have the `author` property, which represents the FK. You will end up with what you want once you serialize such entity. During runtime, you will see entity reference there - an entity with just the PK. It is represented as `Ref<Author>` when you console.log such entity.

Note that you need that `populate: []` there, as otherwise it would be inferred from your `fields` which contains `author` property, and that would trigger the full load of it.

Comment: I wasn't surprised about the 2nd SQL statement (I know how relation loading basically works), I just didn't knew I can alter this behaviour by explicitly setting the (empty) relations to be populated. Didn't find info about it, but now it works.
Thank you Martin!

Comment: It wasn't always like that, but in latest version the `fields` option is also used as a fallback if you don't specify `populate` explicitly, which has this side effect. I'll try to document this somewhere.

Comment: thanks @MartinAdámek that helped me also. One question regarding types, is there a way (using MikroORM) to accurately represent the Loaded type. The result from this query will still show ```Book.author: Author```, when it should be the FK type. Subsequent code thinks it should be ```book.author.id``` instead of ```book.author```. If not, I'll just define my own type for these cases, or cast.

Comment: "> when it should be the FK type"

Nope, its always the entity type, never FK. Only once you serialize the entity, you can get the FK value instead of the full entity object.